# django Tests with django-hosts host_url in Template

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-tests, django-hosts

Is there a way to work with host_url tags in tests?

```
template
{% load hosts %}
{% host_url 'www:index' host 'www' %}

test
@override_settings(DEFAULT_HOST='sub_domain', ROOT_URLCONF='sub_domain.urls')
class IndexViewTest(TestCase):
def setUp(self):
self.client = Client()
self.url = reverse_lazy('index')

def test_index_get(self):
    response = self.client.get(self.url)
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

raises error
django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: 'www' is not a registered namespace

Comment: Please describe "doesn't work": wrong logic or it can't run. Please provide example on github to reproduce

Comment: error says no reverse match.

Comment: no reverse match mean it cant translate the path back to viewset. You can try pass direct url of localhost instead use reverse, or double check your router

Comment: I know what no reverse match means. I don't want to hard code urls.

Comment: AFAIK, your router have something wrong. Per my experience, reverse need suffix -list and -detail to work

Comment: I'm using django_hosts. I don't include subdomain urls in my ROOT_URLCONF.

Comment: I suggest you try apitestcase https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#api-test-cases and reverse, work well for me

Comment: thanks, but it's not the solution I'm looking for.